# Create An Image Upload In PHP For Single User?

Tags: php, image, file-upload

I'm working on a website that will have a simple image gallery page and I want to use PHP to create a file uploader instead of manually embedding all the images into my HTML. I am wondering if it is possible to make this for one single user (so that the whole world cannot upload stuff) and if it is possible without creating a login for that one user.

Comment: Well, you'd have to *identify* the user in some way.  Normally a login is how that is accomplished.  Barring that, how do you plan on identifying the user?

Comment: I'm not exactly sure, that's kind of what I was hoping to find out with this question; if it was at all possible to identify the specified user without creating a separate login.

Comment: A login is probably the easiest way to do this.  It doesn't have to be anything fancy, could even be a hard-coded username and password.  (Well, hard-coded hash of a password.  No reason not to still follow good password practices.)

Comment: @David - "(Well, hard-coded hash of a password. No reason not to still follow good password practices.)" - Amen to that

Comment: I was looking for an alternative way (I'll say it, easier way) to get around it but if creating a login is the best way and most secure way, I'll probably end up doing that. Thank you!

Comment: You could always check their referer - http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php but you could have multiple users coming from one IP address.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It is possible, but definitely not that secure. You could for example append a parameter to the URL: `site.com/?mode=admin` or request a password before doing the upload or something like this.

But as I said, according to the security, it is not a good idea.

Comment: Thank you for the alternative suggestions, I will definitely give these both a try, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

If you are only planning on posting from one place, and security isn't your top concern (you just want to limit so not everyone can post), you could always set the form to only show up for your external IP address.

You can get the IP address in php using:

```
$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']
```

You can find your external IP at whatismyip.com